# Getting the value of a Radio button set by browser autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, browser, autocomplete, radio-button

I'm having problems with getting the current state of a radio button input field that is on a page that has been previously rendered by the browser.  The scenario is this:

- The page containing the input element is rendered, with the first radio button in the group having the 'checked' attribute
- The user selects a different radio button (e.g. the third option), and then navigates to another page
- The user clicks the browser 'back' button to redisplay the page

At this point, the browser autocomplete has set the third radio button to showing as selected, but the first radio button still has the 'checked' attribute.  This means any javascript trying to get the currently selected radio button value returns the first input element's value, not the third one (which is visually selected).

Does anyone know what javascript can be used to return the visually selected radio button, rather than the element that has the 'checked' attribute?

NOTE: I know that I can disable this using `autocomplete="off"` on the input element, but it would be nice to be able to keep the radio button selection, as otherwise the autocomplete is a bit pointless in a scenario using javascript.

I'm actually using jQuery in my live application, so either a jQuery or javascript solution would be acceptable.

Here's some basic html that demonstrates the issue.  You'll need to save the following in a local .html file, load it into the browser, navigate to another page, and then click 'back' to see the issue.

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

    <h1>Radio test</h1>

    <label>
        <input name="test" type="radio" value="1" checked>
        Value 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="test" type="radio" value="2">
        Value 2
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="test" type="radio" value="3">
        Value 3
    </label>

    <div id="message"></div>
</body>

<script lang="javascript">

    var rv = document.querySelector('input[name="test"]:checked').value;
    document.getElementById("message").innerText = rv;

</script>

</html>
```

If you load the page, it will look like this:

[image: RadioTest1]

Select 'Value 3', navigate to another page (e.g. from a bookmark, or entering a url), and then click on the 'Back' button.  The page will now show this:

[image]

i.e. the 'Value 3' radio button appears selected, but getting the value using javascript still shows 'Value 1' is selected (as that is the element with the 'checked' attribute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser restores previous form state when you navigate back. But it happens after your code is executed.

What you can do is to listen to [Window::pageshow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event) event. It will makes sure that your script is ready to read final checked state:

```
window.onpageshow = () => {
  var rv = document.querySelector('input[name="test"]:checked').value;
  document.getElementById("message").innerText = rv;
};
```

Comment: Thanks @yurzui. This fixes the issue that I reported, but I now realise that my actual issue is with jQuery.  All of our code uses the standard 'document.ready' event for initialisation (which all jQuery documentation seems to recommend), but where radio buttons and autocomplete are concerned, it seems we should be using window pageshow instead.